# Is there any way of retrieving a list of poll voters from Instagram stories?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api, instagramapi-mgp25, instagram-story

I know there is an endpoint [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/stories/) for retrieving a list of story id's, but I was wondering if it was possible to get a list of the users who voted on a specific story poll?

There seems to be very little data on stories (even when you export personal account data) and it would be great if this was accessible via the API.

Also I don't want to make my account a Business Account.

Answers don't have to be limited to using the API, I have manually screen shotted the list and joined the screenshots together and used text recognition to get the handles, so any fancy solution that is faster than data entry is welcomed.

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but not using the Instagram Platform API (via https://www.instagram.com/developer) but rather the new [Instagram Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/)

Your account must also be a business account or else you won't have access to the end point.

The endpoint is: `/user/stories` and can be found in the following [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/stories/)

I hope this helps someone, I wasn't able to find a good answer so here's to knowledge-filling.

Comment: Spent 24 hours reading the docs and figuring out the steps to build a simple, personal, one time use application using Instagram Graph API. 

Yea I'll just type it in like a data monkey, scrap that.

Comment: Would this technique be able to retrieve the poll results as well?

Comment: @MeersE.Chahine thanks for your response to this.  That documentation link you posted seems to be dead now, however I assume this might be where that info now is: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media/

...however I cannot find any info about polls there.  Perhaps I am looking in the wrong place, or perhaps it just isn't possible to obtain poll result data via the API?  Does anybody have an update oh this?  Thank you!

Comment: I believe it is no longer possible to obtain it legally due to the updated privacy policy, which states that external people's usernames and avatars cannot be extracted outside the Instagram app, can only be seen in the mobile app now (not even in the website app for the fear of web scraping).

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I'm not familiar with the Instagram API,

I tried to find the AJAX request on my story, and find out that it is as follow:

> https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=<_QUERY_HASH_>&variables=%7B%22reel_ids%22%3A%5B%22<_USER_ID_>%22%5D%2C%22tag_names%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22location_ids%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22highlight_reel_ids%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22precomposed_overlay%22%3Afalse%2C%22show_story_viewer_list%22%3Atrue%2C%22story_viewer_fetch_count%22%3A50%2C%22story_viewer_cursor%22%3A%22%22%7D

'variables' is just a URL encode of:

> {"reel_ids":["<_USER_ID_>"],"tag_names":[],"location_ids":[],"highlight_reel_ids":[],"precomposed_overlay":false,"show_story_viewer_list":true,"story_viewer_fetch_count":50,"story_viewer_cursor":""}

Note, you need to replace <_USER_ID_> with your user ID, And for me <_QUERY_HASH_> was some constant string,

Then, the response JSON can be parsed using a small Python program:

```py
import json

def parse_instagram_json(json_as_str):
    data = json.loads(json_as_str)
    if ("data" not in data) or ("reels_media" not in data["data"]):
        print "Invalid JSON"
        return
    for media in data["data"]["reels_media"]:
        for media_item in media["items"]:
            print "You have {} views".format(media_item["edge_story_media_viewers"]["count"])
            viewer = []
            for v in media_item["edge_story_media_viewers"]["edges"]:
                viewer.append("{} ({})".format(v["node"]["username"], v["node"]["id"]))
            if 0 < len(viewer):
                print ", ".join(viewer)
```

I'm not sure if I'm getting the viewer list or the voter list,

The JSON fields suggest it is the former but you can give it a try and maybe it will be what you was looking for...

Comment: I've been playing around with this too but can't seem to get anything other than the viewer list, I was wondering if you had the key property that the MOBILE instagram app would use to request the voters list too.

The whole JSON data response doesn't include any form of voter list so I'm guessing the instagram mobile app would but I don't know how to access the AJAX request sent by an app on my phone, would you be able to help any further? 

Happy to un-validate my answer and keep it open for you, all I need to find is the property that requests the voters list too. Thank you!

Comment: Hey there, if there are any new updates on this, I am happy to jump into the code.

Comment: @AmadejŠenk It's been 4 years since this question was asked, if you don't think there's an answer here, maybe you should open a new question. Just make sure you write it in a well-defined way so that it actually gets a "correct" answer.

Comment: @YogevNeumann That would be a duplicate. I am looking for an update on the same exact thing.

Comment: I really didn't say to ask the exact same question, I offered to redefine the problem in a better way and ask a less general question, so that it might actually get an answer.
As was nicely answered here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339624/ "You cannot ask the question again, because it would be closed as a duplicate. You could post a new question, but you have to be very careful and state exactly why the original question (not the desired answer) is different from yours." and if you don't think that it is possible, I would suggest to put a bounty on this one.

Answer (score 0):

The new Instagram Graph API, specifically the `/stories` end-point does not provide advanced media information such as polls or stickers. Not even the insights end-point include such interactions insights, only the common ones plus `exits` (they don't even provide `profile_visits` for example).

Comment: This is very misleading and incorrect, I was able to retrieve the polls, images, voters and options here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55681680/get-max-id-of-of-specific-instagram-story-poll-voters and I am close to getting the pagination working, so using the Instagram Private API this is possible and in regards to Graph API you just have to be verified as a business account to get certain API allowances

Comment: Samir, my answer only covers the Instagram Graph API and not another way of fetching Instagram data. If the Graph API provides anything related to polls, my answer would be misleading.
Here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media you can find all available media info, and here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media/insights you can find all available media insights, and that's it.