# Get `max_id` of of specific Instagram Story Poll Voters

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api, instagramapi-mgp25

I know that I can receive the Story data and the Poll voters data using [`getStoryPollVoters()`](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API/blob/master/src/Request/Story.php#L345) which takes the following parameters:

```
* @param string      $storyId      The story media item's ID in Instagram's internal format (ie "1542304813904481224_6112344004").
* @param string      $pollId       The poll ID in Instagram's internal format (ie "17956159684032257").
* @param int         $votingOption Value that represents the voting option of the voter. 0 for the first option, 1 for the second option.
* @param string|null $maxId        Next "maximum ID", used for pagination.
```

I have successfully retrieved the `$storyId, $pollId, $votingOption` from another call and was using the result as the arguments for `getStoryPollVoters()`, however there is one more result without which I don't believe I can retrieve *all* the voters data.

When I request the above I get a max of ~50 responses per poll voting option but I *know* for a fact (based on what I have seen in the official instagram app) that there are more responses.

In the same request, I get the property `more_available: true` and it means that there are more, however it is followed by the property `max_id`, one that is the same optional argument for the function `getStoryPollVoters()`.

My problem is that I would like to set this `max_id` but I do not know how to get the `max_id` for each story poll voting option. I have tried looking through the code to the barebones of the method but all I see is:

```
$request = $this->ig->request("media/{$storyId}/{$pollId}/story_poll_voters/")
            ->addParam('vote', $votingOption);

if ($maxId !== null) {
    $request->addParam('max_id', $maxId);
}
```

It is just an added parameter to the request, one that has little documentation in the repository and has a familiar format across other functionalities such as Feed, Comments, Friends etc. so my attempts to search online have been disappointing.

I wonder if anyone knows how – knowing the $storyId, $pollId & $votingOption – one can query the `max_id` in order to request all voter data?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried looking at https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API/blob/master/examples/paginationExample.php ??

Comment: Seems you need to get `nextMaxId`from the [first response](https://github.com/liamcottle/Instagram-SDK-PHP/blob/master/README.md): `$nextMaxId = $timelineFeed->getNextMaxId();`. So you can start using it in the second request.

Comment: @S.E. Chahine, can you please point me to repo where I can get `getStoryPollVoters()` OR simply point me to API that's get called to fetch voters list for a poll